# Auto-Inc gaps - Id value explodes

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a big issue in production environment, many tables were created with `Int Auto-Inc Primary Key`.

Adding to the fact that our insert mechanizes includes using `Insert Ignore/Insert.. On Duplicate Update` we have reached the Int.MaxValue In a few tables.

I am considering my options and would like to consult:

1. Switching to [innodb_autoinc_lock_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes) = 0
2. Alerting to BigInt in all tables auto-inc column
3. Switching all our application inserts to  `Select + Insert/Update`

I am considering option 1 as this is an `On-Premise` DB and the migration work here is very costly.

As far as I understand from my researching of using `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0` is that it as somewhat of a performance downgrade when handling concurrent inserts. I am planning a benchmark to understand the performance difference, what do you guys think about this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call this "burning ids".  I think it happens with all flavors of `INSERT`, including `INSERT IGNORE`, IODKU, `REPLACE`, etc.

Here is a workaround:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization

That describes how to use 2 SQLs to "normalize" a batch of names and get their ids in an efficient way, and without burning ids.  If you have only a single `name` to insert/lookup, it is still 2 sqls.

`INSERT` allocates as many ids as it *might* need, then burns the ones it did not need.

1. I think the autoinc_mode is global, and hurts performance.
2. Sure, `BIGINT` will work, but I hate to use 8 bytes.
3. And, yeah, my recommendation is *similar to* your #3.  But look closely; there may be some useful differences, especially if you can batch things.

Comment: Isn't using `option 3` bad for performance? Isn't it better to just use the extra 4 bytes and work with the IODKU?

Comment: The perennial tradeoff in computers:  speed versus space.  For batching, my code is probably faster.  For a single row, you are probably correct -- slower.  I offer a workaround; you can choose to use it or not.